# Append launch command from the BEGINNING in launch.json

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I need to run a `python` script using the `mpiexec` command line prefix. The system I'm using requires that everything is run via `mpi`. I know that `vscode` does not support debugging in parallel but surely there must be a way to just run the script as I would in the terminal with this command prefix.

`launch.json` has an "args" option but this appends your args to the END of the command (which is read by the python compiler), I need my stuff to proceed the path of the interpreter, for example:

```
mpiexec -n 1 python3 foo.py
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At present, VSCode does not support the function similar to the command "`mpiexec -n 2 python3 foo.py`" which can automatically execute the process synchronously. However, you can refer to the following workarounds:

1. We can create multiple VScode terminals and manually enter the execution commands respectively (for example: `D:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/.../pythonVScode/test09/ b.py`) In this way, the script will be executed synchronously on different terminals without interfering with each other.
2. With the same principle, we can also use the command "`python FileName.py`" to execute scripts synchronously in different terminals. (Please execute this command in the parent folder directory where the script is executed to be effective. "`cd ParentFolder`")

[image]

Comment: Wow that's really disappointing. What if we only spawn one process in serial, such as "mpiexec -n 1"? Also, I understand that we can use the integrated terminal to run just about anything. I'm interested in running my scripts (without attaching or debugging) with a single keyboard command. Perhaps there are other ways of accomplishing that?

Comment: @liamo -We have submitted this kind of suggestion in Github and it is still voting, so let us look forward to the implementation of this feature. Github link: [Can VSCode automatically run python scripts in two or more terminals at the same time](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094)